# In Device Configuration dialog box in Visual studio 2015, Network host name text box is not present

Tags: visual-studio-2015, deployment, driver, remote-debugging

I am trying to add a new target device for driver deployment following [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/provision-a-target-computer-wdk-8-1). 
In the `Provision the target computer` section there are the steps to add a new target device.

In the **Adding a new target device** dialog box, the **Network host name** text box is not at all present as shown below:

[image: Device Configuration Dialog box with no network host name]

The way dialog box is supposed to look is as below, as the doc I linked above depicts:
[image]

Is this because of any mistake I made or do I have to configure something?

Any solution/help would be highly appreciated.